# Helper class has hidden COM dependencies; who calls CoInitialize?

Tags: c++, com, abstraction

I have a helper class which provides some diagnostic APIs to a host application.  The hidden implementation relies on WMI, which is accessed via Windows COM interfaces.

Implementing a class which is "COM aware" requires some overhead, in the form of calling `CoInitialize/Ex`, using an appropriate Apartment model (single-threaded/multi-threaded).  I'm not sure *who* is responsible for setting that up - my helper class, or the consumer.

So, my question: who is responsible for calling `CoInitialize` and `CoUninitialize`: my helper class, or the host application?  Aside from the helper class, there could be zero additional dependencies on COM in the host application.

**Option A: the helper class calls `CoInitialize` and `CoUninitialize` in the constructor and destructor**

This option is convenient, and effectively 'hides' the COM dependency.  However, the parent application might or might not have already initialized COM, and it might or might not match the helper class's assumed apartment model.  If the models do not line up, the helper class will receive an error from `CoInitialize`.

**Option B: the helper class spawns a separate thread, and calls `CoInitialize` with a single-threaded apartment on the background thread.  All interface calls are dispatched to the background thread and back.**

This could help ensure the helper class has a 'clean slate' to work with, and avoid duplicate COM initializations on any single thread.  It also increases the complexity of my helper class implementation, and adds overhead in the form of thread-switching and hand-shaking.

**Option C: Make a note in the documentation, and require the host application to handle all calls to `CoInitialize` and `CoUninitialize`, before using the helper class**

This one makes the class slightly less 'convenient' to use, because users have additional initialization steps before they can consume the class. It also requires the consumers of the class to *actually read* the documentation, which seems dangerous.

Comment: CoInitialize(Ex) must be called by the guy who created the thread (that will use COM someday, later on).

Comment: That sounds like it eliminates Option A, leaving options B or C.

Comment: *It also requires the consumers of the class to actually read the documentation, which seems dangerous.* If they don't any interface call is going to return `CO_E_NOTINITIALIZED` and will fail gracefully, leading to them reading the documentation (or, more likely, submitting a bug)

Comment: B is probably going to fail. It means you'll create a thread from a component (when are you going to exit it? who is going to do that job? don't think about DllMain)

Comment: The helper class would be a normal C++ class from an outside perspective.  It would use COM pointers in its implementation to access WMI.  

Option B would require the helper class spawn a new thread in its constructor (and join the thread in its destructor).  The background thread would initialize COM, and wait for requests from the helper class's public APIs.  It's not the prettiest.  

Talking through that, and considering that Option C provides a graceful error/exception if the user forgets to initialize COM, makes me think option C is the right answer.

Comment: Do you actually care if COM is running in a STA or MTA?

Comment: As far as I know, no.  I believe WMI queries are apartment agnostic.  I only care that COM is initialized.

Comment: The argument passed to CoInitializeEx makes a *promise*.  You can specify apartment-threaded when the thread will pump a message loop and never will block.  Thus promising that the program is friendly to code that is not thread-safe.  There is only one programmer that knows what the correct promise looks like, the one that wrote the message loop.  Or, perhaps, the one that called that programmer on the telephone to ask why he didn't call CoInitialzeEx().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some excellent points in the comments section, and after further thinking, I've opted for a new **Option D**:

- Create a RAII helper class for initializing COM: `class ApartmentContext`
- Require the `ApartmentContext` as a constructor argument in the helper class.  This forces the user to make a promise that COM has been initialized, by the very existence of an `ApartmentContext` instance.

This has a number of benefits:

- It gives the consumer the flexibility to specify their own threading model.
- It provides an API which clearly communicates the dependency on COM, and forces the user to provide proof of the apartment.
- **Bonus**: the apartment is now RAII-friendly.

Here is the listing for my ApartmentContext class:

```
// Specifies a single-threaded or multi-threaded COM apartment.
enum class Apartment
{
    MultiThreaded = 0,
    SingleThreaded = 2
};

// A helper class used for initializing and uninitializing a COM Apartment.
// The constructor of the ApartmentContext will initialize COM, using the 
// specified apartment model: single-threaded or multi-threaded.
// The destructor will automatically uninitialize COM.
class ApartmentContext final
{
public:
    // Initialize COM using the specified apartment mode.
    ApartmentContext(Apartment mode);

    // Uninitialize COM
    ~ApartmentContext();

    // Get the current apartment type.
    Apartment Current() const;

private:
    ApartmentContext& operator=(const ApartmentContext&) = delete;
    ApartmentContext(const ApartmentContext&) = delete;

    Apartment current_; // Store the current apartment type
};
```

Users will be forced to create one of these, prior to instantiating the helper class:

```
// Somewhere in main...
// Initialize COM:
ApartmentContext context(Apartment::SingleThreaded);
```

The helper class will require the user to provide a context in its constructor:

```
public class MyHelperClass
{
public:
    // The apartment context isn't actually used; it is required by the 
    // constructor merely as a way to ensure that COM is initialized 
    // beforehand.
    // If the class requires a certain apartment mode,
    // it could also check the mode using the "Current" API, 
    // and throw on mismatch
    MyHelperClass(const ApartmentContext&);
};
```

Usage:

```
// Create the helper class, providing the context as a constructor argument
MyHelperClass helper(context);
```

Comment: Hmm, RAII is not as nice as it might seem.  RAII isn't smart enough to know that your code no longer needs to make COM calls.  It will work when the class is created in main(), but you in turn have no guarantee that he did.  Disaster strikes when it is done in an initialize() function.  Reference counting would be the correct approach.

Comment: Perhaps passing the ApartmentContext by value could be an option, where each 'copy' of the context bumps the number of calls to CoInitialize, using the same threading model as the source copy.

Answer (score 2):

Option A with some smarts seems like a good choice. This assumes you don't care what threading model is being used. If you do, you need to explicitly state that the client of the helper shouldn't initialize COM so it can specify the threading model.

```
class HelperThatRequiresCOM
{
public:
   HelperThatRequiresCOM() : m_CoUninit(false)
   {
      // Attempt to init COM as a STA
      HRESULT ciResult = CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
      if(ciResult == S_OK || ciResult == S_FALSE)
        m_CoUninit = true; // COM initialized or already initialized.
      else if(ciResult == RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE)
        m_CoUninit = false; // COM initialized as MTA
   }

   ~HelperThatRequiredCOM()
    {
        if(m_CoUninit == true)
           CoUninitialize();
    }

private:
bool m_CoUninit;

};
```

This will attempt to initialize COM. If it is already initialized as a `STA`, or freshly initialized as an `STA` it will remember that information so that it can call `CoUninitalize` later.

If COM was already initialized as a `MTA` it will remember that and NOT `CoUninitialize` later.

This allows for the calling thread to be free to initialize COM on their own, and if it isn't, you can initialize it yourself.